# Raspberry Pi with USb Ethernet and Plex

Tags: raspbian, networking

been trying to get some more performance out of my Plex server on RPI 3B. It works fine on files up to about 6-7gb, so quite a lot of movies. But above that, it sits and buffers. From what I found through research, I thought the issue was a bottleneck at the network - with the transfer speed maxing at 10mbps. I got a USB To Ethernet adapter and it seems to be working straight out of the box (TRENDNET one), but I am seeing no performance improvements, and movies are now taking longer to load.

I found some blog posts that seem to suggest that I need to edit /etc/network/interfaces to change it to eth1 - but my file has nothing to change in it.

Any help would be appreciated. I have exhausted my googling skills on this. I am trying to setup iperf to do some tests now, but hoping someone has some advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my own question. The USB HDD and Ethernet adaptor share the same bus, so thats probably causing the speed decrease. Going to try it with media from the micoSD Card.